# IBM Rational Change using query functions with oscl_cm query

Tags: ibm-rational, oslc

I'm trying to get a list of Change Requests that match certain conditions, some of these conditions are met by using functions like **has_attr()**.

I would like to ask is it at all possible,  I need for instance to use such function  **has_associated_task(cvtype="task")** is it possible to do that?

For queries I'm using the following pattern:

```
http://ip[:port]/change/oslc/db/dbURI/role/User/cr?oslc_cm.query=change:cvtype="problem" and request_type="Change_Request" and has_associated_task(cvtype="task")&oslc_cm.properties=problem_synopsis
```

this does work without the function term but I would like to extend the search criteria further, is there any other way besides doing a predefined query in change? Is there somewhere a list of terms? like **change:cvtype** (I've tried to see this [http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/rational/change/1.0/][1] but I got a "whoops" from the web server)

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways you could solve this:

[OSLC Resource Shapes](http://open-services.net/bin/view/Main/OSLCCoreSpecAppendixA#oslc_ResourceShape_Resource) - some OSLC providers associate shapes (like schemas) that describe what you can expect from an [OSLC Query Capability](http://open-services.net/bin/view/Main/OslcCoreSpecification#Query_Capabilities).

There isn't a way in the simple query syntax to test for null (or not null), assuming you want to have some condition such as (cvtype="task" and linkedTask != NULL).  To get around this you can simply query based on cvtype="task" and locally filter the results using tools such as XPath or Jena.  Alternatively you can do is look for extensions to the tool you are working with to see if they provide any extensions to the query syntax to support your use case, I don't have this information off hand.